# Optimization of Mysql Join Statement Queries

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT GV.ID
     , XS.SymbolId
     , GS.ID
     , XS.SymbolExchangeId
     , XS.IssueId
     , GE.ID
     , XD.ACTIVE
     , XD.ExchangeId 
  FROM TB_GDS_SECURITY GS
     , WSOD_Vanilla.WSOD_XrefIssueSymbols XS
     , WSOD_Vanilla.WSOD_XrefIssueData XD
     , TB_GDS_EXCHANGE GE
     , TB_GDS_VENDOR GV 
 WHERE XD.CompositeIssueID = GS.ISSUE_ID_TEMP 
   AND XD.IssueId = XS.IssueId 
   AND XD.ACTIVE = 'True' 
   AND GV.VENDOR_SHORT_NAME = XS.SymbolsetId 
   AND GE.EXCHANGE_SHORT_NAME = XD.ExchangeId 
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID 
                     FROM TB_GDS_VENDOR_VENUE_SYMBOL VVS
                    WHERE VVS.ISSUE_ID = XS.IssueId 
                      AND (SELECT ID 
                             FROM TB_GDS_VENDOR GV 
                            WHERE GV.VENDOR_SHORT_NAME = XS.SymbolsetId
                          )
                  );
```

This Particular query takes more than a minute. I want it to be done in lesser time.

the explain statement is as follow:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT GV.ID, XS.SymbolId, GS.ID, XS.SymbolExchangeId, XS.IssueId, GE.ID, XD.ACTIVE, XD.ExchangeId FROM TB_GDS_SECURITY GS, WSOD_Vanilla.WSOD_XrefIssueSymbols XS, WSOD_Vanilla.WSOD_XrefIssueData XD, TB_GDS_EXCHANGE GE, TB_GDS_VENDOR GV WHERE XD.CompositeIssueID = GS.ISSUE_ID_TEMP AND XD.IssueId = XS.IssueId AND XD.ACTIVE = 'True' AND GV.VENDOR_SHORT_NAME=XS.SymbolsetId AND GE.EXCHANGE_SHORT_NAME = XD.ExchangeId AND NOT exists (SELECT ID FROM TB_GDS_VENDOR_VENUE_SYMBOL VVS
    -> WHERE VVS.ISSUE_ID = XS.IssueId AND (SELECT ID FROM TB_GDS_VENDOR GV WHERE GV.VENDOR_SHORT_NAME = XS.SymbolsetId)); 
+----+--------------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys                                          | key                         | key_len | ref                              | rows    | Extra                              |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | XD    | ref  | WSOD_XrefIssueData_UINDX1,WSOD_XrefIssueData_INDX1     | WSOD_XrefIssueData_INDX1    | 21      | const                            | 3981788 | Using index condition; Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | GE    | ref  | TB_GDS_EXCHANGE_INDX1                                  | TB_GDS_EXCHANGE_INDX1       | 63      | WSOD_Vanilla.XD.ExchangeId       |       1 | Using where; Using index           |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | GS    | ref  | TB_GDS_SECURITY_INDX1                                  | TB_GDS_SECURITY_INDX1       | 5       | WSOD_Vanilla.XD.CompositeIssueID |       1 | Using where; Using index           |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | XS    | ref  | PRIMARY                                                | PRIMARY                     | 8       | WSOD_Vanilla.XD.IssueId          |       1 | Using where                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | GV    | ref  | TB_GDS_VENDOR_INDX1                                    | TB_GDS_VENDOR_INDX1         | 62      | WSOD_Vanilla.XS.SymbolsetId      |       1 | Using where; Using index           |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | VVS   | ref  | TB_GDS_VVENUE_SYMBOL_UINDX1,TB_GDS_VVENUE_SYMBOL_INDX2 | TB_GDS_VVENUE_SYMBOL_UINDX1 | 5       | WSOD_Vanilla.XS.IssueId          |       3 | Using where; Using index           |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | GV    | ref  | TB_GDS_VENDOR_INDX1                                    | TB_GDS_VENDOR_INDX1         | 62      | WSOD_Vanilla.XS.SymbolsetId      |       1 | Using where; Using index           |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

After optimizing still it takes around 1.35 min to execute.
Please help me out.

Comment: First, see explicit JOIN syntax.

Comment: You aren't using MySQL JOIN.

Comment: What are the index definitions and cardinality?

Comment: Also, consider providing SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for the relevant tables - especially WSOD_Vanilla.WSOD_XrefIssueData

Comment: One performance disaster is the corellated subquery within a corellated subquery

Comment: how many rows in WSOD_XrefIssueData table and how much with condition active='True' and also share show create table results.

Comment: As an observation, you don't have very many join conditions combining the five tables.  Rewrite the query using proper `join` syntax (as suggested above) and you will probably find that you are doing an unintended Cartesian product somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

As per comment elsewhere, you've not shown us the index defintions.

Most likely the bog cost here is the NOT EXISTS sub-clause. MySQL does not handle push-predictates well, and you've also got a cartesian product in there. I'm struggling to understand what this actually does. MySQL (indeed no DBMS I'm familiar with) can effectively use an index for NOT EXISTS or <> or NOT LIKE. The nested nested query does not appear to serve any function since you already have an explicit join between these tables in the outer query:

```
WHERE...AND GV.VENDOR_SHORT_NAME = XS.SymbolsetId...
AND NOT EXISTS ( [a condition] AND
   SELECT ID FROM TB_GDS_VENDOR GV 
   WHERE GV.VENDOR_SHORT_NAME = XS.SymbolsetId
```

Your only filtering apart from the joins and this ugly NOT EXISTS is "AND XD.ACTIVE = 'True'" - if this column only holds 2/3 values then it will likely be very inefficient to use an index.